# Hot tub wiring extending existing wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, hot-tub

I recently got a new hot tub and unfortunately the new hookup is about 2 feet further from where the old hot tub was. For various reasons it would be difficult to run new wire from the gfci breaker.

I know it would likely be against code, but would putting a waterproof junction box inside the hot tub cabinet be ok? Again, I understand it's probably against code, but is there really any reason not to do it assuming it is all waterproof and done correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a weather proof box at the tub is legal.

Comment: I agree. I can't think of any reason why that would be a violation unless you are modifying the hot tub's manufactured wiring. That would violate the listing. Just putting a waterproof j-box somewhere under the exterior of the tub seems just fine.

Comment: His question was "inside the hot tub cabinet" - but outside is a-ok (correct)?

Comment: As long as the tub is not modified the box could be mounted in a hollow space that is accessible or on the outside. I have done both in the past.

Comment: It depends how the hot tub is *intended* to be wired. If you're supposed to bring your own cables into the tub cabinet, then I don't see a problem.